# Why does T4MVC try to run controller actions from Html.ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, t4mvc

In my controllers I pass in a `IUnitOfWork` object (which is generated from IoC) which is then used in controller actions for database functionality (the `IUnitOfWork` is passed to my service layer).

In one of my views, I want to give a link to the `/Company/View/<id>`, so I call the following:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink(company.Name, MVC.Company.View(company.Id))</li>
```

This is being called not from the `Company` controller, but from a view in a different controller.  The problem seems to be that the `MVC.Company.View(company.Id)` seems to actually be invoking the `CompanyController.View(id)` method itself.  This is bad for 2 reasons.

1) Since the `CompanyController`'s non-parameterless constructor is never called, no `UnitOfWork` exists, and thus when the `View(int id)` action is called, the action's database calls fail with a `NullReferenceException`.

2) Even if `IUnitOfWork` exists, my view *should not* be triggering database calls just so my links are generated.  `Html.ActionLink(company.Name, "View", new { id = company.Id })` doesn't trigger any database calls (as the action method isn't invoked) so as far as I'm concerned `tml.ActionLink(company.Name, MVC.Company.View(company.Id))` shouldn't be triggering any DB calls either.  It's excessive database calls for absolutely no gain.

Is there any reason T4MVC was created to function this way?

---

*Edit:* Here are the declarations for the CompanyController

```
public partial class CompanyController : MyCustomBaseController
{
    public CompanyController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
    }

    public virtual ActionResult Add(int jobSearchId)
    {
    }

    public virtual ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult Edit(Company company, int jobSearchId)
    {
    }

    public virtual ActionResult View(int id)
    {
    }
}

public class MyCustomBaseController: Controller
{
    public MyCustomBaseController()
    {
    }

    public int CurrentUserId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your actually action is never supposed to be called. Can you please provide more details about what your Company controller looks like and what the action method looks like? I don't need the impl details, but just the declarations.

Comment: I have added the controller, constructor, and action declarations that are used in this.  If you meant something else let me know and I'll update it.  Thanks!

Comment: Seems you're missing the method name on the action. Also, could you include MyCustomBaseController and its constructors? My goal is to be able to repro what you see on a small app.

Comment: Sorry I pasted it wrong.  I updated it with the real code from my code-base.

Comment: @KallDrexx ActionLink carries the current Controller inside of it; try `RouteLink` instead. If that works, let me know and I'll write it as an answer.

Comment: @George: Nope, using `RouteLink` is still causing `CompanyController.View()` to be called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange, I'm not able to repro this issue with the code above. What should be happening is that calling MVC.Company.View(company.Id) ends up calling an override of your action method, and never actually call your real action method.

To make this work, the generated code should look like this (only keeping relevant things):

```
public static class MVC {
    public static Mvc3Application.Controllers.CompanyController Company = new Mvc3Application.Controllers.T4MVC_CompanyController();
}

public class T4MVC_CompanyController: Mvc3Application.Controllers.CompanyController {
    public T4MVC_CompanyController() : base(Dummy.Instance) { }

    public override System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult View(int id) {
        var callInfo = new T4MVC_ActionResult(Area, Name, ActionNames.View);
        callInfo.RouteValueDictionary.Add("id", id);
        return callInfo;
    }
}
```

Can you look at the generated code you get to see if it's any different? Start by doing a 'Go To Definition' on 'MVC', which will open up T4MVC.cs (under T4MVC.tt).

Comment: Well That's annoying.  Apparently it just never regenerated the CompanyController T4, because `View()` wasn't in there but all my other actions were.  Wish it was more automatic, but explicitly re-running the T4 seems to have fixed it, and I'm having no more crashes.  Marking as the answer to thank you for helping me out through my idiocy :)

Comment: You may want to check out http://chirpy.codeplex.com/ for a way to automatically run T4MVC.

Comment: oh awesome.  I have used chirpy before for JS consolidation but didn't know it could deal with t4.  Thanks!